# SciPy - ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

So I'm working on a problem where I need to simply use SciPy to perform linear regression to get the weights and statistics on the weights, but I'm getting the error
"ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 11 and the array at index 1 has size 100"

The code is simply:

```
from scipy import stats

x = x_copy
y = y_copy

stats.linregress(x, y)
```

Where x is a dataframe and y is a numpy array.

When doing `x.shape` and `y.shape` I get that x is (100, 11) and y is (100,). Running the exact same matrices in `np.linalg.lstsq` and `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression` both work fine and output the weights, but as far as I'm aware I need SciPy to get the statistics on the weights themselves.

I've also checked `x.dtypes` and all variables are float64, and `y.dtype` also returns float64. I've also tried replacing to `x` in the regression call with `x.to_numpy()` incase there was something with the headers/index but received the same issue.

Any suggestions?

Edit:

````
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_28012/197024375.py in <module>
      4 y = y_copy
      5 
----> 6 stats.linregress(x.values, y)
      7 
      8 x.values.shape

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_stats_mstats_common.py in linregress(x, y, alternative)
    153     #   ssxm = mean( (x-mean(x))^2 )
    154     #   ssxym = mean( (x-mean(x)) * (y-mean(y)) )
--> 155     ssxm, ssxym, _, ssym = np.cov(x, y, bias=1).flat
    156 
    157     # R-value

<__array_function__ internals> in cov(*args, **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py in cov(m, y, rowvar, bias, ddof, fweights, aweights, dtype)
   2426         if not rowvar and y.shape[0] != 1:
   2427             y = y.T
-> 2428         X = np.concatenate((X, y), axis=0)
   2429 
   2430     if ddof is None:

<__array_function__ internals> in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 11 and the array at index 1 has size 100```
````

Comment: Does the same happen with `x.values`?  The array derived from the dataframe?  Check its `dtype` and `shape` as well.

Comment: @hpaulj I just did, and `x.values` has a shape of (100, 11) and its dtype is also float64. It still had the same error as well

Comment: A full traceback might help.  Also review what dimensions the `linregress` arguments must have.  I don't use that function, so am not familiar with its docs.

Comment: I've edited the full traceback into the original question. Also it looks like the only requirement is for the two arrays x and y to have the same length. Which as far as I can tell, they both have the same length of 100

Comment: The docs is a bit vague, but I think it means they must be 1d and the same length.  Your `x.values` is 2d.  It's first dimension is 100, matching `y`, but it has a size 11 2nd dimension.  As you can see from the traceback (and source code) it passes the task on to `np.cov`, which is where the error occurs.

Comment: It appears you would be correct. I reduced the array down to a single column and that fixed it. I guess this particular package doesn't work for more than 1 input variable? I'll have to see if scipy has something else for multiple features